# how to make date/time field independent of the current time zone

Tags: html

Datetime-local depends on the current time zone of the machine. If we want to make it independent of the time zone in date time field what type we should use??

Comment: There isn't one. The current recommendation seems to be to have a datetime-local input and a separate control to choose a time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix a timezone and make it standard.
In python you may use datetime.utcnow()

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 21, 6, 28, 11, 61789)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use library https://momentjs.com/ which can make your work easier

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");

newYork.format();    // 2014-06-01T12:00:00-04:00
losAngeles.format(); // 2014-06-01T09:00:00-07:00
london.format();     // 2014-06-01T17:00:00+01:00
```